# Adding an ssh key to a Xen VM

Tags: ssh, xen, xenserver, ssh-keys

I recently needed to restart a Xen host box, and now I can no longer ssh into the VMs. I was able to before, but now I get `Permission denied (publickey).`

I am not too experienced with Xen, is there a reason it would have removed or overwritten the keys on the VMs when I restarted? How can I get the keys back onto the machines? Can I log into the machines from the host box directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach on console and reset your keys with [`xm console <id>`](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenFaq#head-055e0812e71ae0f61611e211e2a320d20716e2b9).

As to your other question, it might be a service you have set to run on boot (of the VMs). You should look through `/etc/init.d` for anything suspicious. Also check `/var/log/messages` to find any helpful hints.

To get the keys back onto the machine scp them over from the host.

Comment: I get a `xm: command not found`. This is a machine I inherited responsibility for. Any reason `xm` wouldn't be installed?

Comment: @mvid it's the standard tool for managing Xen VMs. ensure you're a privileged user, and install the appropriate package (xen-tools for some distros) if it isn't installed